# need linux equivalent to windows "echo %date% %time% %COMPUTERNAME%"

Tags: linux, environment-variables

In Linux,

```
"echo %date% %time% %COMPUTERNAME%"
```

returns

```
%date% %time% %COMPUTERNAME%
```

not

```
Fri 09/24/2010 10:46:25.42 WXP2010043001
```

as Windows does. 
I need to be able to do this for the logs I'm setting up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command with a format like this:

```
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME"
```

To get hundredths of seconds, you may need to do some text processing like this:

```
DATE=date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%N'
DATE=${DATE%???????}
DATE="$DATE $HOSTNAME"
```

This is because date offers seconds, nanoseconds, and nothing in between!

Comment: Or you can simply type "date", give you the format defined by the locale of the OS.

Answer (score 14):

You can do:

```
dt=$(date)
echo $dt $HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 14):

```
echo $(date '+%Y %b %d %H:%M') Your output $HOSTNAME
```

Outputs:

```
2013 Nov 01 09:11 Your output PEGASUS-SYDNEY-CL2
```

Answer (score 7):

it is also possible to use backtiks caracters for this:

```
echo `date` `hostname`
```

or with (localised) date formating:

```
echo `date +"%a %x %X"` `hostname`
```

Answer (score 2):

As a complement: percentage character is not used to reference variables on any Linux shell. You should use the dollar sign for this.

You should probably read an introduction to Bash ([here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/))

Answer (score 2):

Several people have provided answers based on `date`, but your question requires the short day name (although my UK Win 7 installation doesn't provide this with the ECHO command you specified), which no one has (so far) addressed.

To get this, you will probably want to include `%a` in the format string:

```
date "+%a %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, there is the **date** command. If you don't like the default format, it can be modified. See the manpage of **date**

For hostname, you can use **hostname** command, or **$HOSTNAME** environment variable, if it is set.

With system name, it is more complicated. You can use **uname -a**, sometimes it contains the OS name. Some distributions also have **lsb-release**, but not all of them.